# Android WebView - How to scroll WebView top after page finished?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a `webview` app. The problem I'm facing with this that it's not going up on page finished. It should go up after the page finished but it stuck in the center. Please help me!

**NOT WORKING PART**

```
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
 String description, String failingUrl) {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (pageFinished) {
                        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                        animate(view);
                        showFreeze = false;
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (url.contains("error.html")) {
                    currentUrl = "https://website";

                } else {
                    currentUrl = url;

                }

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pageFinished = true;

/////////////////////////// THIS ONE NOT WORKING /////////////////////////////
                        webView.pageUp(true);
                    }
                }, 250);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
        super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);

        try {
            mWebView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mWebView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }, 200);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}

    }
```

I hope help you.